# Is every evolutionary change an improvement?

Tags: evolution

In evolution, an species mutates and evolves over large genetic time spans. But every big change (say, swimming to walking, or walking to flying) is made up of countless micro-changes over the course of many many years and many many generations.

My question, **does each "micro-change" have to be an improvement over the prior iteration**? Or can evolution initiate micro-changes, knowing the current generation won't see the final result for an arbitrary number of years?

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13680/why-specifically-does-each-generation-on-average-improve-upon-the-design-of?rq=1

Comment: @arboviral Actually, that answer is enough to answer my question. I'm content calling this a duplicate question and closing it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Delighted to help! I'd also suggest taking a look through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_drift, and bearing in mind that 'improvement' depends on the environmental context, which changes constantly.